# Are there any docs on IPInnable and GetPinnableReference()?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to exploit IPinnable and GetPinnableReference(). But I saw there is little documentation in this topic. So I have to ask a few questions here

1. **IPinnable**: Is the IPinnable somewhere used in the framework? Specificially do some C# mechanics rely on it? For example, `fixed` can rely on GetPinnableReference()?
2. **MemoryHandle**: There are three parameters in the MemoryHandle (pointer, GCHandle, IPinnable). Internally the object that holds the IPinnable sometimes need to call GCHandle.Alloc to get the handle. This handle is then handed over to MemoryHandle. When calling Dispose on MemoryHandle, the GCHandle is freed. But in the dispose of MemoryHandle the Unpin from IPinnable is also called. So I have two options now, either calling `Unpin` on the `IPinnable` or calling the `Dispose` on the `MemoryHandle`.m So just to make sure I understood this correctly, do MemoryHandle and the IPinnable object both need to take care of the disposal so that the GCHandle is only freed once? If it even is a GCHandle, because I could also hand over a non GCHandle, in other words simply leave it at default and only hand over a native pointer. Since the MemoryHandle is a struct I cannot put in the disposal of an native memory, I need to put it into the `IPinnable`. So in the end I maybe do not understand why the `GCHandle` is handed over to `MemoryHandle` at all. I simply could also do the cleanup for the `GCHandle` in the `IPinnable.Unpin()`.
3. **GetPinnableReference**: Is there any other place, other than fixed, where the `GetPinnableReference` is used?

It would be nice if someone could guide me to a good documentation around these questions?

Comment: Does [pattern-based `fixed` statement](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.3/pattern-based-fixed.md) spec help you?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: Yes this helps. Thank you. But I'm still searching infos for MemoryHandle and IPinnable.